# How to store JSON data into an object after a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, json, object, fetch-api

I accessed a URL with a fetch request and do not know how to iterate through that data after fetching it.

Here is my code

```
    var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=examplekey';

const response = fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData))
  return response.json();
  
(Object.entries(jsonData['Time Series (Daily)']).forEach(([date, timeSeriesDaily])=> {
    console.log(date); 
    console.log(timeSeriesDaily); 
    console.log(timeSeriesDaily['1. open']); 
  }));
```

Comment: Got it. I changed the code to reflect your comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have some issues in your code. You are trying to iterate throught the JSON data outside of the promise chain. Additionally, you should handle the response and the data inside the then block of the fetch request. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=examplekey';

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonData => {
    Object.entries(jsonData['Time Series (Daily)']).forEach(([date, timeSeriesDaily]) => {
      console.log(date);
      console.log(timeSeriesDaily);
      console.log(timeSeriesDaily['1. open']);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  });
```

In this code, the fetch request is made, and when the response is received, the .json() method is called to parse it as JSON data. Inside the second .then block, you can iterate through the data and log the necessary information. The .catch block handles any errors that might occur during the fetch request.

Comment: Ok, this code works, thanks